# Android: Dynamically send email discretely?

Tags: java, android, email, gmail

So im trying to make it so a user can input information into a few EditTexts and click a button and off the email goes. On my device, where i am connected to the 'from' email, it works. But on other devices in which the 'from' email is not connected it does not send the email then my Gmail account shoots an unknown device alert. 
Question is how do I avoid using the 'from' email and password to avoid this account error, while also making sure the user does not see the 'to' email to avoid the user spamming that email.
    Log.i("SendMailActivity", "Send Button Clicked.");

```
                    String fromEmail = "XXXXXX@gmail.com";
                    String fromPassword = "XXXXX";
                    String toEmails = "XXXXX@gmail.com";
                    List toEmailList = Arrays.asList(toEmails
                            .split("\\s*,\\s*"));
                    Log.i("SendMailActivity", "To List: " + toEmailList);
                    String emailSubject = options.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    String emailBody =name.getText().toString()+"\n" +   message.getText().toString();
                    if(opt.isChecked())
                    {
                        File file = new File(ct.getFilesDir(), "XXXXX.txt");
                        new SendMailTask(MainActivity.this, true, file).execute(fromEmail,
                                fromPassword, toEmailList, emailSubject, emailBody);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    new SendMailTask(MainActivity.this, false, null).execute(fromEmail,
                            fromPassword, toEmailList, emailSubject, emailBody);
                    }
```

Main Activity, options is a drop down that picks the subject. Name is the user input of their name. Message is the user input of the body.

```
public class GMailSender {

final String emailPort = "587";// gmail's smtp port
final String smtpAuth = "true";
final String starttls = "true";
final String emailHost = "smtp.gmail.com";

static String fromEmail;
String fromPassword;
static List<String> toEmailList;
static String emailSubject;
static String emailBody;

Properties emailProperties;
Session mailSession;
MimeMessage emailMessage;

public GMailSender() {

}

public GMailSender(String fromEmail, String fromPassword,
        List toEmailList, String emailSubject, String emailBody) {
    this.fromEmail = fromEmail;
    this.fromPassword = fromPassword;
    this.toEmailList = toEmailList;
    this.emailSubject = emailSubject;
    this.emailBody = emailBody;

    emailProperties = System.getProperties();
    emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", emailPort);
    emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", smtpAuth);
    emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", starttls);
    Log.i("GMail", "Mail server properties set.");
}

public MimeMessage createEmailMessage() throws AddressException,
        MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

    mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(emailProperties, null);
    emailMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

    emailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail, fromEmail));
    for (String toEmail : toEmailList) {
        Log.i("GMail","toEmail: "+toEmail);
        emailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                new InternetAddress(toEmail));
    }

    emailMessage.setSubject(emailSubject);
    emailMessage.setContent(emailBody, "text/html");// for a html email
    // emailMessage.setText(emailBody);// for a text email
    Log.i("GMail", "Email Message created.");
    return emailMessage;
}
public MimeMessage createEmailWithAttachment(File file)
            throws MessagingException, IOException {

    mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(emailProperties, null);
    emailMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

    emailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail, fromEmail));
    for (String toEmail : toEmailList) {
        Log.i("GMail","toEmail: "+toEmail);
        emailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                new InternetAddress(toEmail));
    }

    emailMessage.setSubject(emailSubject);
    emailMessage.setContent(emailBody, "text/html");

    Log.i("GMail", "Email Message created.");


            MimeBodyPart mimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            mimeBodyPart.setContent(emailBody, "text/plain");

            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            multipart.addBodyPart(mimeBodyPart);

            mimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);

            mimeBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            mimeBodyPart.setFileName(file.getName());

            multipart.addBodyPart(mimeBodyPart);
            emailMessage.setContent(multipart);

            return emailMessage;
            }
public void sendEmail() throws AddressException, MessagingException {

    Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
    transport.connect(emailHost, fromEmail, fromPassword);
    Log.i("GMail","allrecipients: "+emailMessage.getAllRecipients());
    transport.sendMessage(emailMessage, emailMessage.getAllRecipients());
    transport.close();
    Log.i("GMail", "Email sent successfully.");
}
```

GMailSender Class, copied from somewhere I do not remember where but do not take credit for this code. 
Finally the SendMailTask class

```
public class SendMailTask extends AsyncTask {

private ProgressDialog statusDialog;
private Activity sendMailActivity;
public boolean sendFile = true;
public File file =null;
public SendMailTask(Activity activity, boolean sendFile, File file) {
    sendMailActivity = activity;
    this.sendFile=sendFile;
    this.file=file;
}

protected void onPreExecute() {
    statusDialog = new ProgressDialog(sendMailActivity);
    statusDialog.setMessage("Getting ready...");
    statusDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    statusDialog.setCancelable(false);
    statusDialog.show();
}
@Override

protected Object doInBackground(Object... args) {
    try {
        Log.i("SendMailTask", "About to instantiate GMail...");
        publishProgress("Processing input....");
        if(!sendFile)
        {
            GMailSender androidEmail = new GMailSender(args[0].toString(),
                    args[1].toString(), (List) args[2], args[3].toString(),
                    args[4].toString());
            publishProgress("Preparing mail message....");
            androidEmail.createEmailMessage();
            publishProgress("Sending email....");
            androidEmail.sendEmail();
        }
        else
        {   GMailSender androidEmail = new GMailSender(args[0].toString(),
                args[1].toString(), (List) args[2], args[3].toString(),
                args[4].toString());
            publishProgress("Preparing mail message....");
            androidEmail.createEmailWithAttachment(file);
            publishProgress("Sending email....");
            androidEmail.sendEmail();

        }
        publishProgress("Email Sent.");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        Log.i("SendMailTask", "Mail Sent.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        publishProgress("Email Not Sent.");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e2) {
        }
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public void onProgressUpdate(Object... values) {
    try
    {
    statusDialog.setMessage(values[0].toString());
    }
    catch(Exception e) {}
}

@Override
public void onPostExecute(Object result) {
    statusDialog.dismiss();
}
```

}

Again this code works on devices connected to the 'from' email that has been set up by me. I am looking for a way for users to send me an email without seeing my email. Any alternative or fix would be appreciated.